# How to add third-party dependencies in android/app/build.gradle in Expo projects to prevent them from being overwritten during prebuild

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to add two dependency packages, such as these two. If I manually modify the build.gradle, the manual modification will be overwritten when I execute prebuild --clean.

com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:18.0.1
com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:2.2

try plugin,modules,mods. Cannot achieve the desired result.

As long as Android supports it, it doesn't matter about iOS.